# For a time series plot, how to set the x axis to calendar time without weekends

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to plot a time series (pricing data for a forex future contract). Time is given in `yyyymmdd HH:MM:SS` string format. Price is in `double`.

The time series spans over a week. However, the timestamp for the data points are always on weekdays. *Is there a built-in method to display the appropriate x-axis labels and scaling but without weekends?*

I can currently display the time series by converting the timestamp in string to [`datenum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) and arrange x-axis automatically with [`datetick`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html). But I would like to know how to exclude weekends on the x-axis. Or exclude any extended interval of time from the grid where there is no data.

For a visual, please see example at the end. If one can exclude the large empty space due to including the weekend (Apr 10 was a US holiday), the plot can become more legible by focusing on where there is actually data.

The data points themselves are exclusive to weekdays. But between `plot` and `datetick`, grid points on weekends are created whenever the time series spans over a week. `datetick` is helpful because it detects the appropriate scaling for x-axis grid and applies the corresponding grid labels all in one go. If you see `datetick` as a part of the solution, is there a way to remove particular grid points after using `datetick`?

Example:

```
T=[7.378903958333334e+05;7.378967076388889e+05]; % converted from "20200409 09:30:00" and "20200415 16:59:00"
C=[0.7166;0.7090]; 

grid on
plot(T,C,'.')
xlim([min(T),max(T)])
datetick
```

If you are interested in tinkering with the same plot, please retrieve the data by c&p into Matlab cmd from [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/3ZAjSF0d). The same lines above will produce the following plot.

[image: Example]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211781/discussion-on-question-by-argyll-for-a-time-series-plot-how-to-set-the-x-axis-t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such features. Probably, because this essentially makes the x-axis discontinuous, which is (usually) not desirable.

You will have to create a synthetic x-axis to achieve this by sorting out the the weekends (or rather the not business days).
This is the standard plot (the business days are blue)

```
% create data
T = 7.3789e+05+(0:5:100)/10.';
C = rand(size(T)); 

% is a busniess day?
lg = isbusday(T);

% standard date plot
plot(T(lg),C(lg),'o', T(~lg),C(~lg),'o')
datetick('x','ddd')
```

Now let us get rid of the other days and set the `xTickLabel` manually:

```
T = T(lg);
C = C(lg);
% plot without time-axis
plot(C,'o')

% --- get ticks
xTick = get(gca,'XTick');
% get which ticks are integers
lg = isreal(xTick) & rem(xTick,1)==0;
XTick_new = xTick(lg);
% --- create new tick label
xTickLbl_new_num = NaN(size(XTick_new));
% make sure they are within the limits
lg = XTick_new >= 1 & XTick_new <= length(T);
xTickLbl_new_num(lg) = T(XTick_new(lg));
% convert to string (arbitrary format)
xTickLbl_new_str = strings(size(xTickLbl_new_num));
xTickLbl_new_str(lg) = datestr(xTickLbl_new_num(lg),'ddd');
% set new label
set(gca,'XTick',XTick_new,'XTickLabel',xTickLbl_new_str);
```

Have a look on the results: left the standard version and on the right the version with manually set tick-labels.
[image: comparison]