# How to adjust grid density when plotting a timeseries

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is there a way to adjust grid density when plotting a [timeseries](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.html)?

For example, starting with a csv file containing [data here](https://pastebin.com/xDJ9Gbkg), whose time points are every day since last February.

```matlab
T=readtable(filename); % filename is the full file name of the csv file
ts=timeseries([T{:,2}],cellstr([T{:,1}]));
plot(ts,'.')
grid on
```

The result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8RFe.png) where the plot is correct and the 4 grid labels are properly spaced. But at the same time, for 502 time points, there are only 4 grid labels.

How should I adjust the grid density for the horizontal axis?

---

I learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61244563/3181104) one way to generate custom grid points. I would love to learn any different methods. Maybe there is a simpler method as the requirement relaxes from custom grid points to custom grid density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB gridlines are drawn based on where the [xticks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticks.html) and [yticks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yticks.html) are. So for your case, you can change your `xticks` property to adjust the horizontal gridline density.

---

You can check the current ticks with the functions `xticks()` and `yticks()`, and it will give you an array of current ticks location. For example, after making a scatter plot with your data, I can do:

```
>> xticks()

ans = 

  1×8 datetime array

   2020-01-01   2020-04-01   2020-07-01   2020-10-01   2021-01-01   2021-04-01   2021-07-01   2021-10-01
```

In this case, to set a new `xticks` value, I need to give the function an array of `datetime` type, since the x-value is of a `datetime` type.

So if I want to draw a gridline for every 30 days, you can do something like:

```
% Generate an array of datetime from the first date in your data,
% then incrementing by 30 days until the last day in your data.
tick = your_data.date(1) + (0:30:length(your_data.date))
% Update xticks location
xticks(tick)
```

[image: Example updated xtick location]